# Setting geckodriver to path with heroku

Tags: python, heroku, geckodriver

Despite having geckodriver in the same folder that I'm pushing through using heroku, the compt still says that `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.` I've also initiated the driver through code using, 

  `driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver", options=something, 
  firefox_profile=FireFoxOptions)`, and I still seem to get the same issue. Please help! I've been stuck on this for days and adding buildpacks to my Heroku app also did not seem to help. Thank you!

Comment: Exactly the same issue here. Do anyone, or the author of the post, have found solution?